# How to remove swiffy white background from animation

Tags: html, flash, css, google-swiffy

How do I delete or remove the white backgroundColor that swiffy puts on my animation?

Comment: Cheka - is it helpful for you?

Comment: No bro, :S i continue stuck because the animation i get i need it in a div and swiffy do that for me but i cant access to the backgrouund color

Comment: Cheka - I have updated my answer - try it know please

Comment: Cheka if the answer are helpful for you please upvote it. If it solved your problem - accept it. I post it here cause as for today you have 5 questions and 0 accepted answers and also 0 upvotes.

Answer (score 3):

```
stage.setBackground(null);
```

add it before `stage.start()`

Answer (score 0):

Go to the upper right hand of the editor: 
Site Settings->Appearance->Colors and Fonts

*Update:*

you can a backgroundColor Element or create a style to overwirte it:

```
<style>
   svg 
   {
      background: none !important;
   }
</style>
```

Comment: I haven't been able to get this suggestion to work either.  I believe the reason is because Google set the in-line style when rendering.  I'm unfamiliar with !important; however, it doesn't seem to override inline styles.

Answer (score 0):

I've read in other locations that the solution to this issue to search for "backgroundColor: nnnn" in the Swiffy output and to remove this element completely. This did not work for me until I discovered that Google have broken the ability to do this in the current version of the Swiffy runtime. If you also change:

src="https://www.gstatic.com/swiffy/v5.2/runtime.js"

to

src="https://www.gstatic.com/swiffy/v5.1/runtime.js"

at the top of the file you should find that the transparent background works correctly.

best regards